# Using Facebook Social Plugin Comments

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have the Facebook Comments Social Plugin. It works fine and is installed perfectly. But how can I be notified when someone leaves me a comment so I can respond and also approve the comment?

I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Well I found where to see all your comments: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXview=recent_comments But I still do not understand how I can get email notifications or something when someone leaves a Comment.